# ASP.NET / C# Respond.Redirect function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know after the `ID=`, I want to pass in the ID of the user , I have made the query on other page

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from registration where ID=@bid", con);
SqlDataAdapter apd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", Page.Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
con.Open();
apd.Fill(ds, "registration");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
FormView1.DataSource = ds;
FormView1.DataBind();//
```

Here is the query string -

```
Response.Redirect("Users.aspx?ID=< Get the id from database for the certain user >);
```

Here is the part that i want to know how it works

My "project is ": whenever you login as user with `ID=1` you go to a page `users.aspx?id=1` and you get the info for the user 1, if user 2 logins you get info for user 2 etc..

Comment: You can Request.Param["ID"];

Comment: can u be more direct ? cuz im really newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you pass an ID through a URL, you can request the parameter of the URL by using Request.Param["ID"];

Say you want to display the user information on a page, on the page load, you'd have

```
int id = Request.Param["ID"];
// some code here to fetch the user data from the database
// more code to return / display the user content
```

Request.Param will basically check a URL for any parameters.

Example: http://www.mywebsite.com/profile?id=1&somethingelse=27

If you use

```
Request.Param["id"]; // this will return 1
```

and if you use

```
Request.Param["somethingelse"]; // it will return 27.
```

Comment: string id = Request.Params["ID"];          Response.Redirect("Users.aspx?ID=" + id); i put it like this.. as i understand but... screw me ..

Comment: You should use `Request.QueryString` instead of `Request.Params`, which is a more general data store for all the keys/values sent from the client.